# PDF: hyperlink/position

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

Is there a "console way" to find out the position and target of hyperlinks within PDF-documents?
The popular tools for converting pdf-to-* end up with text or very broken html documents. That's why I wonder if there is a way to know where (exact position) within the PDF we can find a link and where it is pointing to.

Looking forward to helpful reply.
Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the language/platform, so here is a .NET solution:

Docotic.Pdf library (disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle) can be used to retrieve all hyperlinks in a document. You may retrieve bounding box, text and other properties of a link. Please take a look at "[Extract text from link target](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Pages%20and%20Navigation/TextFromLink)" sample.

Answer (score 0):

I've just published a Python solution on Github. http://github.com/j-norwood-young/PDFLinkFinder